# What am doing wrong in this piece of fibonacci code in python docs vs my re implementation?

Tags: python, fibonacci

Python docs:

```
>>> def fib(n):
    a,b=0,1
    while a<n:
        print a,
        a,b=b,a+b

>>> fib(2000)
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597
```

My reimplementation:

```
>>> def fib2(n):
    a=0
    b=1
    while a<n:
        print a
        a=b
        b=a+b

>>> fib2(2000)
0
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
```

Comment: It would be easier to implement it as a recursive function like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence-in-python

Comment: But won't making it recursive for a huge n make the program slower than the pyth docs implementation?

Comment: @Aditya_Pan I doubt that it would became slower. But a potential problem for a large n would be it would run out of stack space and throw a stackOverFlow error. Doing it recursively is best suited for a functional programming language. Its better to do it iteratively in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between

```
a,b=b,a+b
```

and

```
a=b
b=a+b
```

is that in the second one, `a` is assigned value of `b`, and then `b` is assigned the sum of `a` and `b`, which means it is twice its original value.

Consider:

```
a = 1
b = 2
a,b = b,a+b
```

This gives

```
a==2 (old value of b)
b==3 (sum of 1 and 2)
```

Contrarily:

```
a = 1
b = 2
a = b
b = a + b
```

which gives:

```
a==2 (old value of b)
b==a+b==2+2==4 (twice the old value of b)
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that, when you do:

```
a,b=b,a+b
#     ^
```

the `a` that I marked is the *original value* of `a`, not the updated value.  This is because Python always evaluates what is on the right of the `=` sign before it evaluates what is on the left.

When you do this however:

```
a=b
b=a+b
```

the `a` in the second line is the *new value* of `a` that was assigned in the line above.  This causes your calculations to be off.

For more information, here is a reference on [assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) in Python.

---

To get the same behavior as the function in the Python docs, you would need a temporary variable to save the original value of `a`:

```
tmp=a
a=b
b=tmp+b
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> def fib2(n):
...     a=0
...     b=1
...     while a<n:
...         print a, # The comma causes everything to be printed on one line
...         tmp=a
...         a=b
...         b=tmp+b
...
>>> fib2(2000)
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597
>>>
```

Of course, doing just:

```
a,b=b,a+b
```

is a lot more pythonic.  Although I would recommend you put some spaces:

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

Readability is everything in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fib2(n):
a=0
b=1
while a<n:
    print a
    a=b
    b=a+b
```

Here when you do `a = b` and then `b=a+b`
This is equal to `b = b+b`
This is not what you want

Now this is what you want :

```
def fib2(n):
a=0
b=1
while a<n:
    print a
    tmp = b
    b = a+b
    a = tmp
```

But `a,b=b,a+b` this is lot more pythonic

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a detail with the comma syntax. Try:

```
c=b
b=b+a
a=c
```